# How to convert display value of every cell in grid?

Tags: extjs, grid

I have panel with combobox and gridpanel inside. I need to convert every value from grid by using of 'change' action in combobox according to new and old values in combobox.
I added to combobox next raws:

```
listeners: {
    change: function(field, newValue, oldValue){
        switch(JSON.stringify({"from": oldValue, "to": newValue}){
            case ..:
                makeSmthWithEveryCell();
                break();
            case ..:
                makeSmthElse();
                break();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

And I need to write converter for every cell according to case, which have been chosen.
I suppose, it will be smth like that:

```
   myGrid.getStore().each(function(rec){
       convertCellValue(???);
   });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of extjs are you using ? and depending of each case are you going to update the cells for  diferent records....?

Comment: Extjs 4.2. I need to update all cells in one grid (from radians to graduses, for example) by changing of combobox value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you almost have the solution, just add the following code inside the each function:

```
 myGrid.getStore().each(function(rec){
   rec.set('myField',myCombo.getValue());
 },this);
 myGrid.getStore().commitChanges();
 //add the following line only if the grid data is not updated
 myGrid.getView().refresh();
```

Comment: It's not fully decision. I need rec.set to every cell in rec, and also change value according to chosen cb value. So I should get value of cell and make a conversion of this value (for example, from radians to graduses). I can write rec.set several times, but is it correct descision for this case?

Comment: And also I can write rec.get several times. Any short decision?

Comment: You can create a renderer function that do the conversion and reusing in all cells that apply and in that function use the combobox selected value, and when change just call myGrid.getView().refresh();